# Semantics - Passing in an implemented interface into methods

Tags: java, c++, c++11

Consider the following interface:

```
class MyInterface
{
   virtual bool test(void * param) = 0;
}
```

Can do something like this to implement the interface?

```
MyInterfacemyInterface = new MyInterface()
{
   bool test(void * param)
   {
        return true;
   }
}

myClass.setInterface(myInterface);

----- OR -----

myClass.setInterface( new MyInterface()
{
   bool test(void * param)
   {
        return true;
   }
} );
```

**PS: This method is done in Java. Wondering the something similar exsts in C++.**

Comment: `MyInterfacemyInterface = new MyInterface()` What should this be?? I'm pretty sure that's not valid [tag:c++] nor [tag:c++11] syntax.

Comment: I have already tried to compile this and it didn't work, which is why I am asking here.

Comment: No. You cannot define a class like that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Its done in Java and it is quite useful, so I was wondering if something similar exists in C++.

Comment: Is this about adding interface implementation to existing class in runtime?

Comment: @mk1 So c++ isn't java, period! If you want to implement an interface you'll need to have an instantiatable class inheriting it and pass an instance of this one.

Comment: @c-smile I dont think so. Not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: If it is a simple interface with one method you can use lambdas in C++11

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand - just curious. Unfortunately, it seems in StackOverflow, curiosity kills the cat.

Comment: @mk1 Nevermind! I've retagged your question to be more appropriate.

Comment: @mk1 You've had a comment about overboarding source files (for implementations of the interface), ake a look at my answer to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can get to the java equivalent of an inlined interface implementation is to put a private class into your compilation unit:

```
#include "MyInterface.hpp"

namespace {
    struct MyInterfaceImpl : public MyInterface {
        virtual bool test(void * param)
        {
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

And use it elsewhere in this file (e.g. from stack local instances).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time such a pattern is used in Java for event handling/callback purposes. If it close to your use case then consider something like this:

```
class Widget {
  std::function<void()> _callback;

  void setCallback(std::function<void()> callback) { _callback = callback; }

  void fireCallback() { if(_callback) _callback(); }
}
```

And in galaxy far far away:

```
int main() {

     Widget *pw = new Widget();

     auto callbackFunction = []() { alert("called back!"); } // C++ lambda

     pw->setCallback( callbackFunction );
     ....
}
```

When needed that Widget instance may decide to call its fireCallback method and so you will see alert("called back!") on your screen.

Comment: This is probably the most useful answer. The Java idiom is mostly used to provide ad-hoc function definitions, and the corresponding idiom in C++ looks very different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to do something similar to what is done in Java and create some kind of anonymous class that is used only in one place.

This is not possible in C++ the same way that it is in Java. 
Something similar that you could do is have your 'interface' (although it will no longer be that) use lambdas, which are specified the moment where you instantiate the class. This is not exactly what you're looking for, and is not very idiomatic C++, but can be done.

Comment: Can you please show an example of `lambdas` used for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

*Strictly speaking*, there's no such semantics in C++. If you want to pass an interface to a function, you take a pointer or reference to it as a parameter, and implement the interface in a separate class.

You'll have one of the following member function (following your names)

```
myClass::setInterface(MyInterface* ptr);
//or
myClass::setInterface(MyInterface& ref);
```

and then the implementation

```
class MyInterfaceImpl : public MyInterface{
    //Stuff
}
```

You can then pass a pointer to a `MyInterfaceImpl` to `setInterface`, but you can't define an implementation *on-the-fly*  and pass it this way to the function.

**EDIT:** If you want something close to this behavior, consider πάντα ῥεῖ answer, or implementing the class just before you create an instance and pass it to the function, though that's quite unusual in my experience, and clutters the code with local class definition)